# Post data has form input but Django modelform is not saving it

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

I've looked through a bunch of the other posts - but I can't find anything quite fitting to my scenario. I've got a bit of data that is coming across in the POST but then when I save the form - the data is not appearing in the database.

I'm a bit perplexed as to why this is and I've tried various things, but none of them really seem to apply to my situation. Most have to do with the data not being posted, my data is posted, it's just not saving.

I've got the following model:

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    METHODS = (
        ("Cash", "Cash"),
        ("Check", "Check"),
        ("Credit Card", "Credit Card")
    )
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    method = models.CharField(
        max_length=15,
        choices=METHODS,
        default="Credit Card"
    )
    stripe_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    check_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is my PaymentForm:

```
class PaymentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    method = forms.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "readonly": "True",
            })
        )
    amount = forms.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2,
        max_digits=6,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "readonly": "True",
            })
        )
    stripe_id = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.HiddenInput(),
        required=False
    )
    check_number = forms.IntegerField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = (
            'amount',
            'method',
            'stripe_id',
            'check_number',
        )

    def clean_check_number(self):
        method = self.cleaned_data["method"]
        check_number = self.cleaned_data["check_number"]
        if method == "Check" and not check_number:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Check number is required.")
```

Here is my `view.py` function that relates to the POST:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Create a copy of the POST data so we can input data for CC payments
        post_data = request.POST.copy()
        # Set the PaymentForm with the copied data (muteable)
        # required for some of the stripe stuff we do
        payment_form = PaymentForm(post_data)

        if 'stripeToken' in request.POST:
            # This is wrapped in extensive try/catch in reality but I left
            # it out for brevity
            charge = stripe.Charge.create(
                amount=stripe_cost,
                currency="usd",
                description="Payment",
                source=request.POST["stripeToken"],
                receipt_email=request.POST["stripeEmail"],
            )
            # add things to the form that aren't there
            # from the stripe reply
            payment_form.data['method'] = "Credit Card"
            payment_form.data['stripe_id'] = charge["id"]
            # This part works fine
        if payment_form.is_valid():
            # either a non-stripe payment
            # or the next step after the stripe stuff is don
            payment_form.save(commit=False)
            print(payment_form.data)
            payment = payment_form.save()
            # The data saves to the DB, but the check_number is empty!
        messages.success(request, "Thank you for your payment!")
        return redirect("my_app:index")
```

That print statement after the form is valid prints out like this:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['3blahblahblah'], 'amount': ['9.10'], 'method': ['Check'], 'check_number': ['123455'], 'stripe_id': ['']}>
```

The issue I'm having is this: when a user selects `Check` as payment and saves the payment (with a check number) the check number isn't saving to the database.

As we can see, the `request.POST` data shows all the data there (including check number) - but in the database the `check_number` is not being stored when the `.save()` is running.

What might make that happen and how do I ammend that?

Comment: What happens if you remove `check_number = forms.IntegerField( .... )` from the form and you just use the default model form implementation of the field?

Comment: The `check_number` still comes across in `request.POST` - but does not save to the database.

Comment: And you have run your latest migrations?

Comment: Yes, all migrations are up to date.

Comment: Hmmm, and if you remove the `blank=True, null=True` in the model and then create a run a new migration? Besides that I have no idea...

Comment: Those are needed on the model to allow the form to submit as valid in instances where a check_number is empty (for example with a Stripe payment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be printing `form.cleaned_data`, not `form.data`, after the is_valid. If you did, you would see that check_number is empty. The reason for that is that you don't return anything from your `clean_check_number` method. You always need to return the cleaned value from those methods.